# HashMap get gives null with String as key

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I've a problem with the get(Object key) method from HashMap.

```
hm.put("597068",o1);
hm.put("ws-5896",o2);
```

When I try the following line of code it gives the correct object:

```
hm.get("597068");
```

But when I try to get Ws-5896, then it gives Null. Why?

```
hm.get("ws-5896");
```

**Update**
HashMap declaration:

```
private static HashMap<String,Ort> hm = new HashMap<String,Ort>();
```

Comment: Can you post the lines where `HashMap` is declared?

Comment: Assuming `o2` is not `null` and wasn't removed by you or by another thread (if any), then could be a problem of the key you're passing. Make sure it is the same `String`, specially check the `-`.

Comment: Can you compare the key with which you put the value and the key with which you extract the value ?

Comment: Perhaps `o2` is `null`?

Comment: @Harmlezz I bet you it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately HashMap won't distinguish between a null value and no entry when performing a [HashMap.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29).

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if
>   this map contains no mapping for the key.

Have you checked whether the key is contained in the map using [HashMap.containsKey()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) ?

> A return value of null does not necessarily indicate that the map
>   contains no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map
>   explicitly maps the key to null. The containsKey operation may be used
>   to distinguish these two cases.

Comment: the containsKey() returns false, which is strange because if I check keySet() then "Ws-5896" is in it.

Comment: That looks like a case issue, yes ? Ws-5896 vs ws-5896

Comment: Indeed, I solved it. The search function in my code changed every string to lower case. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score -1):

Print hm.keySet() to the screen and you'll see where your code fails. I bet you are looking for "Ws-5896" key and HashMap is **case-sensitive**.

Comment: HashMap isn't case-sensitive. Case-sensitivity would depend upon the key equals implementation (in this case, String.equals() which *is* sensitive)

Comment: @Brian Agnew I meant that exactly!